# How can I get keys pressed by the keyboard, even while the window isn't focused?

Tags: python

I'm making a key press overlay for rhythm games. How would I go about obtaining keyboard inputs outside of the Python window's focus?

I would assume you would use the `keyboard` module, but I can't find any documentation on it other than how to have it record and simulate key presses. Upon importing it and looking at possible functions, I see that there are some that appear to have the functionality of getting keys down/up. I have no idea how to use them though. I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track with the `keyboard` module but maybe one of you guys know.

Comment: See https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard readme

Comment: Absolutely no clue how I didn't think to look on the actual dang github page. Thanks.

Comment: see also [pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)